# How to change image of button?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

**When i press button it changes image into green but it quit dark,but its original color like lookup button image,so what's wrong in my code?**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImage *clear_img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"0.png"];
    UIImage *clear_hover_img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"0_hover.png"];
    clear=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    [clear setTitle:@"Clear" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //clear.tag =12;
    clear.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:32];

    if(clear.selected=TRUE){
        [clear setBackgroundImage:clear_img forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [clear setBackgroundImage:clear_hover_img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    [clear setFrame:CGRectMake(1, 360, 159, 50)];
    [clear addTarget:self action:@selector(clearInput)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:clear];
}

-(void)clearInput {

    textfield.text = @"";
    UIImage *lookup_img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"0_.png"];
    [lookup setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [lookup setBackgroundImage:lookup_img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. Could you rephrase your question?

Comment: Formulating the question in sane english instead of copy & pasting Google Translate output helps people immensely trying to understand what you mean.

Comment: what is Your problem explain it.then only we give suggestion

Comment: my button change image into green image when i press ok?
but its color is so dark the orignal color is like lookup button
so where is mistake in my code?

Comment: Do if(clear.selected==YES) instead (clear.selected = TRUE)

Comment: when i am doing
if(clear.selected==YES) or if(clear.selected == TRUE)
its not coming in if condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For state TouchUpInside, Button Image Opacity decrease to 0.5.
try this-

```
if(clear.selected == TRUE){
    [clear setBackgroundImage:clear_img forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [clear setBackgroundImage:clear_hover_img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [clear setBackgroundImage:clear_hover_img UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

Comment: You want the equality operator, not the assignment operator.

Comment: There is no such state like `UIControlStateTouchUpInside` this is an event. I believe to use `UIControlStateHighlighted`. This solved my problem.

Comment: its not working 
[one setBackgroundImage:one_img forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

Comment: my fault -     [clear setBackgroundImage:clear_hover_img forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];

Answer (score 1):

I think you wants to set Clear button Image as Lookup button. you had done with that but when you press on clear button the image get some darken.

If my understanding is right then you had done:

```
[clear setBackgroundImage:clear_img forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[clear setBackgroundImage:clear_hover_img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

add this line too:

```
[clear setBackgroundImage:clear_img forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Hope this helped